# Point a wildcard subdomain in go daddy to a heroku app

Tags: godaddy, heroku

So I have purchased a domain on go daddy by the name let's say **example.com**. Now I want to direct all ***.example.com** to a nextjs app hosted on heroku.

I followed the standard process to point any subdomain to a heroku app which was

1. Add a custom domain to heroku app by name ***.example.com**.
2. Copy the dns target given by heroku
3. Create a cname record in go daddy's DNS records page for the site with * as name and heroku dns target as data.

Now when I try to hit sub.example.com the site is unreachable. The above procedure seems to be invalid for wildcards only. When I repeat the same process for any single subdomain let's say **sub.example.com** it works perfectly.

I have followed the answer mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38922194).
I know wildcards are supported on heroku as mentioned [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#add-a-wildcard-domain).

Also FYI the main domain example.com points to another server hosted separately.

This how dns record on go daddy looks like

```
Type  |  Name  |         Data           |  TTL
------------------------------------------------
CNAME |   *    | example.herokudns.com. | 1 hour
```

On heroku side

```
Domain Name   | DNS Target 
---------------------------------------
*.example.com | example.herokudns.com
```